# how to entry in log models , when i update the another model in django?

Tags: django-rest-framework

i am working on two models, 1st one is inventory model and 2nd one is inventory log model, when i update inventory model, it must create an entry in inventory log model. how to do this?
here is my code.

```
    def put(self,request):
    id = request.data.get('id')
    print(id)
    inventory = Inventory.objects.get(pk=id)
    inventorylog = InventoryLog.objects.get(pk=id)
    # log = InventoryLog.objects.all()
    serializer = InventoryPutSerializer(inventory,data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.update(instance=inventory, validated_data=serializer.validated_data )
        serializer.update(instance=inventorylog, validated_data=serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

here is my serializers

```
`class InventoryLogPutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = InventoryLog
    fields = ('last_modified')

class  InventoryPutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

class Meta:
model = Inventory
fields = (
'user',
'product',
'alert_level',
'last_log',
)`

model fields in inventory
user(fk)
product(fk)
alert_level
last_log(fk)

model fields in inventory_log
user fk
product fk
date
last_modified
change
cahnge_type
associated_invoice fk
description

Comment: You can make use of signals for such cases.

Comment: Here a link to one such tutorial. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html